# Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an issue running the gazebo server. It always crashes with a segfault.

Here is the debug log:

http://pastebin.com/c51fvTz9

This is how I launch gazebo:

```
 <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="debug" value="true"/>
 </include>
```

I've looked around, more users seem to have this problem but there does not appear to be a definitive solution.

I run Ubuntu 12.04 with nvidia drivers (GT650M) installed by bumblebee. OpenGL appears to work (glxgears) and rviz works fine.

Any ideas?

Edit: this was using gazebo 1.9.3 and ROS Hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124996/inappropriate-ioctl-for-device/) by [Alpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8726/alpha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-31**:
Which version of gazebo are you using? Have you tried with the latest version compiled from source?

**Comment by [Alpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8726/alpha/) on 2014-01-31**:
Thanks for the advice, I'll try the latest version of Gazebo (currently the default that comes with hydro) and post the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well I figured out what caused it. The urdf file was using a hokuyo laser, which in turns uses the GPU to do calculations. Disabling the GPU usage fixed the segfault.

Disable it by changing

```
<sensor type="gpu_ray" name="laser_scanner_sensor">
```

and

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
```

To

```
<sensor type="ray" name="laser_scanner_sensor">
```

and

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
```

---

Originally posted by [Alpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8726/alpha/) with karma: 18 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing this is less of a problem with gazebo, and more of a problem with running `gdb` from `roslaunch`.  [Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/48056/using-roslaunch-with-gdb-gives-error-tcsetpgrp-failed-in-terminal_inferior-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device/) is an answers.ros.org question that produces the same errors you are seeing, and [here is a bug report](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/223) that I filed with `ros_comm` about this same issues.

I'm guessing if you set `debug` to `false` the ioctl error will disappear.  If you are still seeing segfaults, something unrelated to this error is causing the problem.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8726/alpha/) on 2014-01-31**:
Well the ioctl error will disappear (unknown if it is occuring or not, but it is not displayed) but the segfault remains. I was under the impression that the ioctl error and the segfault were related, but perhaps they are not. How else could I determine the cause of the segfault?